# How to deploy play app with a huge public folder?

Tags: deployment, playframework

In my **public** folder I have a few hundreds of MB of files (some pdf files).

Is there any way when using `play playapps:deploy my-project` to ignore this folder?

Otherwise I have to wait a lot to upload the entire application each time when I do an update...

Answer (score 1):

I have received the answer of this from Guillaume Bort.

I will paste it here for the others:). Note, that this solution is available for [playapps](http://playapps.net) hosting only.

> The storage/data folder is mapped to application/data

So, I can copy files trough SSH in storage/data and they will be available in application/data because of the mapping.

That's a great solution!!!

**UPDATE**: Of course, you have to define a route for this, eg:

```
GET     /data/                                  staticDir:data
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing that stuff on an external service like amazon S3

Comment: Yeah but it's somehow ugly to pay hosting on playapps (my case) and buy another host for space on amazon....